# get custom headers of AFHTTPRequestOperation

Tags: xcode, afnetworking

I attempt to get custom header key using AFHTTPRequestOperation, I try using allHeaderFields but nothing, here is header response

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server  nginx
Date    Tue, 19 Feb 2013 16:38:29 GMT
Content-Type    text/html
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
Connection  keep-alive
Set-Cookie  AUTH-ID="fjArrnmlyNMU9kfIu38Oc0LS451Y/UaMn0rb5sKj46CxmfJj8y8yr8CfwOewItFY"; HTTPOnly
X-AUTH-TOKEN    mfy+426BNZdq1h92As3oXdZbf2iOI7wV7EOEUMAV3hAqtY7cOnWvA4df7h6RfjeD
Location    /home.php
```

I use AFHTTPRequestOperation like this

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]initWithRequest:request];
    [operation  setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
NSDictionary *headerData = [[operation response] allHeaderFields];
        if ([headerData objectForKey:@"X-AUTH-TOKEN"] != nil)
            token = [headerData objectForKey:@"X-AUTH-TOKEN"];

        NSLog(@"headers = %@", headerData);
        NSLog(@"token = %@", token);
        ...
}
failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        ...

}];
```

but X-AUTH-TOKEN key don't appear in headers NSLog, I'm sure the header key is present because I use Charles proxy to debug and Charles show me the X-AUTH-TOKEN key. Maybe the 302 status code is the problem, can anyone help me please? 
Thanks.

[EDIT] when I try to show status code of response, it's 200.

Comment: Hey, I have same issue. have you got any solution? please tell me....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved using some tweaks of AFURLConnectionOperation for intercept redirect response.